# Running multiple instances of an application with different arguments using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, arguments, multiple-instances

I'm trying to build client server program. 
So I should run my program simultaneously with diffrent ports.
The program gets the port through the arguments.

What is the way to do that?
Thank you

Comment: Don't forget to vote for our answers if you feel they have value, and accept one when it answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

When creating launch configurations (as @Konstantin mentions)  and adding parameters to the *Arguments>Program Arguments* tab you can use a variable so that eclipse will ask you for the parameter on every launch.  ex: `-port ${string_prompt}`

Answer (score 1):

If you pull down the menu under the Run toolbar button, you will see "Run Configurations...". This will open a dialog to let you define any number of launch configurations. Then use this pull-down menu to launch your app with different parameters using different launch configurations.